# Changing https-address of submodules in .git/config to ssh-address

Tags: git, git-submodules

I need to use ssh forwarding-agent to enable git cloning on remote servers. The repository has submodules which were originally added with their `https` addresses. In order for forwarding agent to work, I think I need to change those addresses to their corresponding `ssh` address.

Will changing these addresses in `.git/config` solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`git config --global url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) to substitute URLs on the fly. Something like

```
git config --global url.<new-url-with-https>.insteadOf git@<server>:<user>/<repo>.git
```

See more examples in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+insteadof

Comment: Thanks! It must be the way to do it, but do I need to push the changes so that other repos can also have this change?

Comment: The change is in the config and you cannot push git configs. You should disseminate the information outside of git.

Comment: It worked for me. For others, look here to understand what is above doing https://gist.github.com/Kovrinic/ea5e7123ab5c97d451804ea222ecd78a. This change can be global or local depending on the requirements. I do it on the remote server before calling any git clone.

Answer (score 5):

The URL of the module is stored in `.gitmodules` at the root of your sandbox. This file is tracked as part of the Git repository. If you make the change here and commit it, it will be visible to other users of the Git repo.

When you call `git submodule sync` and then `git submodule init`, the URL is resolved and copied to `.git/config`. When you call `git submodule update`, the submodule is cloned and its URL is also found in `.git/modules/<module-name>/config`.

To permanently change the URL, edit `.gitmodules` and call `git submodule sync` and `git submodule init` again.

To temporarily change the URL, make these two changes instead:

Change the URL in `.git/config` for the submodule

Go inside the submodule and call:

```
git remote set-url origin <new-url-with-https>
```

The second command will update the URL in `.git/modules/<module-name>/config` which is the `.git` folder for the submodule.

EDIT: If the module and submodules all live on the same server, using relative URLs for your submodules will solve the problem once and for all: each sandbox will fetch the submodules using the same protocol the main repo was cloned with. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68120599/3216427

Comment: Hum, I did more tests and I'm pretty sure my answer is wrong. Git tracks the remote yet somewhere else, that needs to be updated, probably instead of both the changes I suggested. I'll leave this answer up for now but delete it once a correct solution is found.

Comment: I was just going to try this. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: So, it seems like my suggestion works as long as you don't call `git submodule sync` again. When you call `sync`, it resets the URL in both places. This is obviously not what you want, you'll want something stable.

Comment: OK, answer fixed. `.gitmodules` is the source for the URL, from which the others are set.

Comment: The solution from @phd is probably better, but now that mine also actually works, I'll leave it up as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, github deprecated usage of `git://` protocol and I wanted to update the submodules in my repository to use `https://` instead of `git://`.

I did the following:

```
$ vim .gitmodules # Change all the git:// URLs into https:// URLs
$ git submodule init
$ git add .gitmodules
$ git commit -m "Update submodules"
$ git push origin main
```

You can do the same to convert URLs to `ssh://`.