# How do I use Git submodules with AWS CodeCommit and SSH access?

Tags: git, ssh, git-submodules, aws-codecommit

I'm working on a project which uses AWS CodeCommit, and has 2 main apps, plus a submodule of shared components.  On Windows I was able to clone all 3 repositories, and then I navigated into the sharedComponents directory in each of the main apps, and ran

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

This linked the shared components to the main app, and all was fine.

On Mac, however, I first had difficulty in cloning the repositories at all; eventually I got this working by setting up an ssh public private key pair (saved in ~/.ssh) and cloning that way.  However, the `git submodule` command that I used above doesn't work in this scenario, and gives the error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/MyRepoName/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

which is the error I get when it can't access the security credentials.

So, I suspect that I need to tell `git submodule update` to use SSH mode, or to call the ssh version of the URL or something like that, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I've answered a similar question before. If both the main repo and its submodule are on the same server, you can use a relative URL. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55242865/3216427

Comment: In your case it's the other way around — ssh instead of https: `git config --global url.git@git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:.insteadOf https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/`

Comment: @phd Personally I like the relative URL solution better, because I don't have to configure it in each sandbox. Using a relative URL means that however a developer has cloned the main repo, the other repos will be cloned using the same mechanism. When I move to a different server, too, I don't have to change anything in the submodule configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I linked the wrong question. My answer about using relative URLs is to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68120599/3216427 . I think I need to have a better write up for the idea, though!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  In my project root directory, I went into .git and modified config.  I changed the Shared Components URL to ../MySharedComponents and that seems to have worked.