# How to specify the git submodule URL dynamically in .gitmodules file?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

My repository's `.gitmodules` file is currently like this :

```
[submodule "app/src/main/assets/my-submodule-repository"]
    path = app/src/main/assets/my-submodule-repository
    url = git@github.com:my-organization/my-submodule-repository.git
    branch = main
    recurse = true
```

Instead of having a unique hardcoded value for the submodule URL, is it possible to have a certain submodule URL depending on what the main repository's URL is? If the main repository has a HTTPS protocol URL, then use an HTTPS URL for the submodule, and if the main repository has a SSH URL, then use a SSH URL for the submodule too?

Comment: You can use a relative URL. I wish I had a better write up for this, I've answered it in comments several times. This is relevant, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68120599/3216427 For you, `url = ../my-submodule-repository.git` should do what you want.

Comment: OK, so this was the nudge I needed. I've rewritten my answer there, so now I'm comfortable pointing you there for your answer.