Adding local repo as submodule always resolves to Github
This is such a bizarre thing.  I'm trying to add local repo ProjectB as a submodule of ProjectA.  I'm very familiar with the process and commands to work with submodules, but trying to run git submodule add ../ProjectB ProjectB in the root of ProjectA causes git to try to clone from Github, not the local repo (I've omitted from this the other submodule commands, but they were run).  I've tried multiple times, resetting everything each time (.gitmodules, .git/config, .git/modules/ProjectB)
I'm not sure if that's a bug or a questionable design choice, but digging in I ran GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git submodule add --force ../ProjectB ProjectB and indeed it is trying to clone from Github.
So--I remove all references to Github from ProjectB: package.json, git remote, everything I could find.  I'm pretty sure I got them all, but when I try the above again, it still resolves to Github instead of the local repo.
I am looking for an explanation of this behavior, not the unfortunately common "Why are you using submodules?" style of non-answer.
Does someone have an explanation for this behavior?  It doesn't make sense how git even KNOWS where that repo is on Github since I've removed all references to Github from ProjectB, much less why and how it's choosing to clone from Github instead of where I told it.

The problem is that ../ProjectB is interpreted by Git as a relative URL, relative to the main sandbox's remote. That's a very useful feature in general, which I use often, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/68119419/3216427 . You'll need to make it explicitly a local path remote, or maybe give it a full path.

Interesting, I just tried adding a submodule with /full/path/to/ProjectB, and I get the error fatal: transport 'file' not allowed. More research required, but this may just not be supported.

Ah, you can force it with -c protocol.file.allow=always. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6106503/3216427  Or --force as you did.

Explanation
The problem is that ../ProjectB is interpreted by Git as a relative URL with respect to the main sandbox's remote, i.e., wrt ProjectA's remote in this case.
The is useful when you store your project and its submodules on the same server. If you fork everything, move to a different server, or move everything to local storage, the same submodule definitions will remain valid in all cases.
Solution
If you want the file protocol when the main sandbox uses a remote one, you'll have to be explicit about it:
git submodule add --force file:../ProjectB


Thank you for the explanation.  I'm not wild about designing for convenience over consistency, but we'll leave that aside.
I had previously tried multiple variations on the command you showed, including the protocol.file config, file: protocol (including the missing //), absolute file path (whose different behavior now makes sense thnx to your explanation), etc.
Tried again just now and same error: fatal: transport 'file' not allowed.  I set the config on both projects A and B, no difference.
But just knowing "why" is better, thnx.
